# Deleting records from table where ST_DIstance from another record in another table is greater than a certain amount

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm currently learning SQL on the run, and have come across a situation where I'm trying to delete records from a table depending on a function result. I can select the records of interest with the following query -

```
select ST_Distance(a.reporter_location, b.report_location) as dist, b.hex, b.flight, b.report_timestamp, b."isMLAT" from reporter a, planereports b where a.name like 'Home1%' and ST_Distance(a.reporter_location, b.report_location) > 400000.0 order by b.report_timestamp;
```

but I'm unsure how to place this into a conditional for a delete statement. Any ideas? Brain is turning to mush.

Comment: What are the names of the primary keys of your tables?

Comment: hex for planereports, and name for reporter. However, the planereports key will not be unique.

Comment: A combination of the planereport's hex and report_timestamp fields should be unique.

Comment: From which table do you want to delete?

Comment: I want to delete from the planereportstable. The device I query sometimes gives bad values for lat/lon, which manifests itself as an improbably large distance for a device that is line of sight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your select statement as input for the where clause of the delete statement. Hava a look at the docs of [delete](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html).

```
delete from planereports
where  hex in (select b.hex
               from   reporter a,
                      planereports b
               where  a.name like 'Home1%'
               and    ST_Distance(a.reporter_location, b.report_location) > 400000.0
               );
```

Comment: I think that particular form might delete all the records for that particular hex value, not just the bad ones?

Comment: This query deletes only the bad ones.

Comment: The select statement returns the ```hex```es of the bad records. The delete statement delets a record only if its ```hex``` was returned by the select statement.

Comment: Well, I just tried it, and it deleted all the records that had a p[articular hex value, where what I wanted was all the records that had the condition ST_Distance(a.reporter_location, b.report_location) > 400000.0 return true.